# Upper and lower deck in bus booking app not saving data when change deck

Tags: java, android, layout, android-recyclerview

I am working on a bus booking app. I created a layout for sleeping bus. It created properly. I have upper and lower deck in bus. So when i open layout it will by default open lower deck. And if select some seats and go to upper deck then again come to lower deck then it will create new adapter and i cannot see selected seats.

[image: When selecting Seats from lower deck 1st time]

[image: Going to the upper deck]

[image: Coming back to lower deck]

[image: Selecting same seat again]

**SearSelectionSleeperActivity**

```
public class SeatSelectionSleeper extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{


    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewupper;
    SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter seatAdapter;
    List<SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails> seatDetailsList;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerUpper;
    List seatNo;
    TextView txtSeatNo;
    TextView fare;
    public Bitmap seatIcon;
    public Bitmap seatSelect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seat_selection_sleeper);


        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.busDeckSelectionButtons);

        final RelativeLayout driver = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.driver);

        seatIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sleeping_available);
        seatSelect = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sleeper_select);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerViewupper = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerupper);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
        layoutManagerUpper = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        seatAdapter = new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter(SeatSelectionSleeper.this, loadBustListSeats());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(seatAdapter);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId){
                    case R.id.lowerDeck:
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        seatAdapter = new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter(SeatSelectionSleeper.this, loadBustListSeats());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(seatAdapter);
                        driver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        recyclerViewupper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    case R.id.upperDeck:
                        recyclerViewupper.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerUpper);
                        seatAdapter = new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter(SeatSelectionSleeper.this, loadBustListSeatsUpper());
                        recyclerViewupper.setAdapter(seatAdapter);
                        driver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        recyclerViewupper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class SeatDetails {
        String name;
        boolean isBlank;
        boolean isSelected;

        public SeatDetails(String name, boolean isBlank, boolean isSelected) {
            this.name = name;
            this.isBlank = isBlank;
            this.isSelected = isSelected;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            isSelected = selected;
        }

    }

    public List<SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails> loadBustListSeats() {

        seatDetailsList = new ArrayList<SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails>();
        int seatSerialNumber = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            if (isBlankSeat(i)) {
                seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("", true, false));
            } else {
                if (i == 0) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("A5", false, false));
                }   else if (i == 2) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("A1",false, false));
                }  else if (i == 3) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("A2",false, false));
                } else if (i == 4) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("B5",false, false));
                } else if (i == 6) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("B1",false, false));
                }  else if (i == 7) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("B2",false, false));
                } else if (i == 8) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("C5",false, false));
                } else if (i == 10) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("C1",false, false));
                } else if (i == 11) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("C2",false, false));
                } else if (i == 12) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("D5",false, false));
                } else if (i == 14) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("D1",false, false));
                } else if (i == 15) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("D2",false, false));
                } else if (i == 16) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("E5",false, false));
                }  else if (i == 18) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("E1",false, false));
                }  else if (i == 19) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("E2",false, false));
                } else if (i == 20) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("F5",false, false));
                }else if (i == 22) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("F1",false, false));
                }else if (i == 23) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("F2",false, false));
                }
            }
        }
        return seatDetailsList;
    }

    public List<SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails> loadBustListSeatsUpper() {

        seatDetailsList = new ArrayList<SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails>();
        int seatSerialNumber = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            if (isBlankSeat(i)) {
                seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("", true, false));
            } else {
                if (i == 0) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("A6", false, false));
                }   else if (i == 2) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("A3",false, false));
                }  else if (i == 3) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("A4",false, false));
                } else if (i == 4) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("B6",false, false));
                } else if (i == 6) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("B3",false, false));
                }  else if (i == 7) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("B4",false, false));
                } else if (i == 8) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("C6",false, false));
                } else if (i == 10) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("C3",false, false));
                } else if (i == 11) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("C4",false, false));
                } else if (i == 12) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("D6",false, false));
                } else if (i == 14) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("D3",false, false));
                } else if (i == 15) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("D4",false, false));
                } else if (i == 16) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("E6",false, false));
                }  else if (i == 18) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("E3",false, false));
                }  else if (i == 19) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("E4",false, false));
                } else if (i == 20) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("F6",false, false));
                }else if (i == 22) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("F3",false, false));
                }else if (i == 23) {
                    seatDetailsList.add(new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails("F4",false, false));
                }
            }
        }
        return seatDetailsList;
    }


    public boolean isBlankSeat(int i) {
        if ((24 - (i - 1)) < 4)
            return false;
        else
            return i % 4 == 1 ;
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    }



    public void seatSelected(int pos)
    {
        seatDetailsList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
        charge = charge + amt;
        fare.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
        seatNo.add(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName());
        txtSeatNo.setText(seatNo.toString().replace("[","").replace("]",""));
        seatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void seatDeselected(int pos)
    {
        seatDetailsList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
        charge = charge - amt;
        fare.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
        seatNo.remove(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName());
        txtSeatNo.setText(seatNo.toString().replace("[","").replace("]",""));
        seatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class SeatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


        class ViewHolderOriginal extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            ImageView imageView;
            ViewHolderOriginal(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

            }
        }


        class ViewHolderBlank extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            ViewHolderBlank(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

            }
        }



        public Context cntx;
        public SeatAdapter(Context context, List<SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails> list){
            this.cntx = context;
            seatDetailsList = list;
        }

        // 0= Original view 1= Blank View
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if((getItemCount() -(position-1))<4)
                return 0;
            else
                return position % 4 == 1 ? 1 : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return seatDetailsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (viewType == 1)
                return new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter.ViewHolderBlank(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_blank, parent, false));
            else
                return new SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter.ViewHolderOriginal(inflater.inflate(R.layout.seatrow_grid_sleep, parent, false));
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if (holder instanceof SeatSelection.SeatAdapter.ViewHolderBlank) {

            } else if
                    (holder instanceof SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter.ViewHolderOriginal) {
                SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsList.get(position);

                if (seatDetails.isSelected){
                    ((SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter.ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(seatSelect);
                }else {
                    ((SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatAdapter.ViewHolderOriginal) holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(seatIcon);
                }

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsList.get(position);

                        if (seatDetails.isSelected){
                            seatDeselected(position);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            seatSelected(position);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time when you change the adapter you are creating new `SeatSelectionSleeper.SeatDetails` object list from `loadBustListSeats()` and `loadBustListSeatsUpper()` so it will make your comparative object `seatDetails.isSelected` as false when you change the adapter.

One easy solution you can try to use you seatNo list object to achieve that,

Instead of using the below code in your adapter,

```
if (seatDetails.isSelected)
```

Use this,

```
if (seatNo.contains(seatDetails.getName()))
```

Because, you are adding and removing when seat selected or removed the seat name in this list.